# Calling ASMX Service from jQuery Client Side Code

Tags: jquery, web-services

I have a VS 2010 project locally where I have a ASMX service running locally. I created another VS 2010 project which has to consume that local ASMX service. For some reason whenever I trigger the service it gives me 500 Internal Service Error. Both applications are running on separate ports.

```
 $.ajax(

    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:22059/Mobile/HOCWebService.asmx/GetCategories",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType:"application/json",
        success: function (response) {

            alert(response); 

        }
    }

    );
```

Comment: What's the Exception that is raised? Also, have you looked at the stack trace?

Comment: No exception is raised. In FireBug I see url as OPTIONS GetCategories. What does that mean? No response is returned which is also weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Both applications are running on separate ports.

That's the problem. You are violating the [same origin policy restriction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You cannot send AJAX requests to services that are not hosted on the same origin as the page containing the script (different ports => different domains).

Answer (score 0):

MAKE SURE THAT YOUR ADDING THE FOLLOWING LINES OF CODE ABOVE THE WEBSERVICE CLASS

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

AFTER ADDING THE CODE LOOK LIKE BELOW

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WSDataService : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

THIS ABOVE LINE OF CODE WILL ALLOW THE AJAX CLINET CALL TO CONSUME WEBSERVICE.

THEN YOUR CLIENT WILL START COSUMING

Comment: Please take some time to read about SO's formatting tools in the FAQ, and please also observe the policy of NOT POSTING EVERYTHING IN CAPS...